# Creating dynamic dialog page in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

The following code creates a dialog page in jQuery Mobile:

```
<div data-role="page" id="dialogPage" data-dialog="true" data-theme="b" data-close-btn="right">
    <div data-role="header">
    <h2> replace html </h2>
    </div>
         <div role="main" class="ui-content">
         <p> replace html </p>
         <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a">close dialog page</a>
         </div>

</div>
```

The page is currently called with:

```
<a href="#dialogPage" data-transition="none">open dialog page</a>
```

How can I make this dialog page dynamic so that I can replace the html in the "header" and "main" content areas when the user clicks on a unique anchor element. I need to be able to create multiple anchor tags that can each dynamically alter the content of the same dialog page. For example:

```
<a href="#button1" data-transition="none">button1</a>

<a href="#button2" data-transition="none">button2</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the `pagecontainerbeforeshow` trigger:

```js
var data = {
    "dialog-1": {
      title: "Choose one:",
      content: [
        '<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">',
        '<legend>Horizontal controlgroup, checkbox:</legend>',
        '<input name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a" type="checkbox">',
        '<label for="checkbox-h-2a">One</label>',
        '<input name="checkbox-h-2b" id="checkbox-h-2b" type="checkbox">',
        '<label for="checkbox-h-2b">Two</label>',
        '<input name="checkbox-h-2c" id="checkbox-h-2c" type="checkbox">',
        '<label for="checkbox-h-2c">Three</label>',
        '</fieldset>'
      ].join("")
    },
    "dialog-2": {
      title: "Search:",
      content: [
        '<label for="search-2">Search Input:</label>',
        '<input name="search-2" id="search-2" value="" type="search">'

      ].join("")
    }
  },
  calle = "";

$(document).on("vclick", "a[data-dialog]", function(e) {
  calle = $(this).data("dialog");
});

$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function(e, ui) {
  var pageId = ui.toPage.attr("id");
  if (pageId == "dialogPage") {
    $("#dialogPage .ui-title").text(data[calle].title);
    $("#dialogContent").html(data[calle].content);
    $("#dialogPage").enhanceWithin();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h2>List Page</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <a class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" href="#dialogPage" data-dialog="dialog-1" data-transition="none">Callee 1</a>
      <a class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline" href="#dialogPage" data-dialog="dialog-2" data-transition="none">Callee 2</a>
    </div>
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <h3>Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="dialogPage" data-dialog="true" data-theme="b" data-close-btn="right">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h2> replace html </h2>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content ui-page-theme-b">
      <div id="dialogContent"> replace html </div>
      <a href="pg_2" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a">close dialog page</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question. The code you posted works great, but how would I modify it so that I can call multiple anchor elements, each with their own unique 'id' and then dynamically change the dialog page depending on which anchor was pressed? I updated the question, so hopefully it makes more sense as to what I was asking.

Comment: you need to set the origin of the data when the anchor is used (clicked or tapped). see my updated answer.

Comment: Works great! Thank you. I tried to change the "href" for the "close dialog page" from "pg_2" to "#". It's a much better way to create a back button. I just wanted to change that value for anyone using this in the future.